# WooCommerce admin product custom checkbox field not saving value

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, woocommerce, custom-fields

i created custom checkbox on product options, but stuck in saving data.
I tried all possible variants, but without success.
Where i am going wrong?
thanks

This is code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_sku', 'custom_checkbox_field' );
function custom_checkbox_field(){
    global $post, $product_object;

    if ( ! is_a( $product_object, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
            $product_object = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
    }
      
            
    woocommerce_wp_checkbox(
    array(
        'id'            => 'custom_checkbox_field',
        'value'         => empty($values) ? 'yes' : $values,
        'label'         => __( 'Label', 'woocommerce' ),
        'description'   => __( 'Description', 'woocommerce' ),
        )
    );
    
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_custom_field' );  
    function save_custom_field( $post_id ) {
    

     // grab the product
     $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );

      // save data
      $product->update_meta_data( 'custom_checkbox_field', isset($_POST['custom_checkbox_field']) ? 'yes' : 'no' ); 
      $product->save();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some missing thing in your code and your last hooked function hook can be replaced with a better one since WooCommerce version 3. Try the following instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_sku', 'custom_checkbox_field_product_options_sku' );
function custom_checkbox_field_product_options_sku(){
    global $post, $product_object;

    if ( ! is_a( $product_object, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
        $product_object = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
    }

    $values = $product_object->get_meta('custom_checkbox_field');

    woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array(
        'id'            => 'custom_checkbox_field',
        'value'         => empty($values) ? 'yes' : $values, // Checked by default
        'label'         => __( 'Label', 'woocommerce' ),
        'description'   => __( 'Description', 'woocommerce' ),
    ) );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'save_custom_field_product_options_sku' );
function save_custom_field_product_options_sku( $product ) {
    $product->update_meta_data( 'custom_checkbox_field', isset($_POST['custom_checkbox_field']) ? 'yes' : 'no' );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you @loictheaztec, now working
Where i can see in Woo files, code of saving, creating fields and metaboxes?
Thanks one more time

Comment: @ВладимирКятипов To get the product custom field value you can use from the product Id `get_post_meta( $product_id, 'custom_checkbox_field', true );` or from the product object `$product->get_meta('custom_checkbox_field');`